# jquery targeting next ID

Tags: jquery

I have a table colspan that I'd like to add a class to with jQuery:

`<td colspan="3" id="colspan-123">`

And I tried with:

`$(this).closest(\'#colspan-123\').next(\'#colspan-123\').toggleClass("row-notop");`

But that's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ids must be unique. Can you share your hTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am one of the upvotes for "ids must be unique". They must!

However you could use this selector and add a class:

```
$("td[colspan=3]").addClass("row-notop");
```